Inappropriate ESC activation & steering wheel misalignment after lower steering column replacement
As I describe in Steering clunk - 2012 Audi Q5, I replaced the lower steering column in my wife's 2012 Audi Q5 because the lower u-joint was worn & stiff.
However since then, in order to drive straight I have to turn the steering wheel about 15 degrees left, and the ESC sporadically activates for no reason (low speed, dry road surface, no loss of control).
Both ends of the lower steering column are keyed such that it seems impossible to fit it 'slightly wrong' - it's either correct or it's a full 360 degrees off. There isn't a spline which could be off by one notch or something like that.
Did I get a defective part? Or am I wrong and there is some way that I managed to fit it 15 degrees off?
Update: this was a defective part.
The "flats" on the attachment points on the u-joints on each end of the shaft were not positioned at the same relative angle to each other compared to the original Audi part, resulting in the approx 15 degree offset in the steering wheel.
Apparently this causes the ESC to panic when it sees the steering wheel turned but the car still moving in a straight line.
I've temporarily put the original Audi shaft back in (after giving the u-joints as much lubrication as I child get in to them) and the steering is I've again straight and the ESC doesn't panic.

You may have to calibrate the steering angle sensor, last paragraph; https://www.audiq5.net/steering_column_removing_and_installing-535.html. This requires Audi's Vehicle Diagnostic Tester.

@FDryer that page seems to be referring to the upper section of the steering column, which I left alone. The lower section I replaced was significantly less complicated than that (no wiring involved), and is shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YZeSoNWGoxQ
